# Bootstrap fail.. 4 columns with gutter in one row (last columnt is in new line)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I have a problem with bootstrap.. In last project, everything was fine, but now, I really don't know what to do.. I used customize for customizing bootstrap (3), selected only grid system & responsive utilities (the same way as in last project).

Columns: 4

Grid gutter width: 16

Tablet: 720px + grid-gutter

Desktop: 980px + grid-gutter

Large desktop: 1140px + grid-gutter

After a few hours of seraching I decided ask here.
URL: http://jebe.rosaweb.eu/ Why the last column goes on new line? It should not do this :( I know, if I set padding to 0px it will be fine, but I need that padding.. It should pass one row.. 
Does anybody know where is the problem?

Thank you and I hope you understand my english

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong, you're using

```
<div class="col-md-1">
    aa
</div>
```

when it should be

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    aa
</div>
```

and if you want to scale columns based on screen size, you could use something like:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    aa
</div>
```

This means your columns will take 3 "grid columns" (out of 12) on large screens, 3 on medium screens, 4 on small screens and full width on extra small screens (tablet and smaller)

for more information, take a look to [Bootstrap Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: look above.. I said I set columns: 4, so my col-md-1 is ok.. do you think I should use 12 columns instead and use col-md-3 ? I will try, but i think it doesn't help

Comment: again, you need to read the link I posted. You're confusing the amount of columns you see in your layout with the amount of columns Bootstrap uses. Just to make it short: a Bootstrap row is a grid of 12 columns (unless customized, which is not your case). So, to make 4 EQUAL columns, you need to have 3+3+3+3 grids. See what I mean?

Comment: Can i get your customize css? @DanielRosskoRosa